# Extract value in some range

Tags: sql

I have next table

points:

```
min max level
0   5    1
6   10   2
11  15   3
16  20   4
```

and I need to extract level according points. If I have 7 points then level will be 2 and query is next:

```
select level
from points
  where 7 > min
  AND 7 < max
```

what I need is get highest level if points are more then 20, for example if I have 35 points level should be 4. How I can do it?

Comment: if I understand your problem correctly, then : `SELECT level FROM points WHERE max > 20` should be what you looking for

Comment: then it will return all levels

Comment: "points are more than 20"? Isn't points a _table_?

Comment: Why it should be level 4 if the points are 35? Shouldn't it be level 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set max in the last row to null:

```
| 16 | null  | 4
```

And your query becomes:

```
SELECT level
  FROM points
 WHERE :score >= min
   AND (:score <= max OR max is null)
```

Remark: it is better to define your ranges as [min,max[:

```
min max level
0   6    1
6   11   2
11  16   3
16       4
```

Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT level
  FROM points
 WHERE :score >= min
   AND (:score < max OR max is null)
```